# Prettier not detecting solidity

Tags: solidity, parser, vscode, formatting

Prettier formatting is working for typescript but not for solidity.
I have tried uninstalling and installing Prettier and Solidity(by JuanBlanco) extension again but still no luck.
Below are my settings

```
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "[solidity]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "JuanBlanco.solidity"
  }
```

I also tried
 `"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"` for solidity but it also did not solve the problem.

The code in .sol file is correct and is compiling so code correction is not an issue apparently.

Also, I see this disabled sign with Prettier when .sol file is open in editor.

[image: Prettier disabled sign]

I have also tried doing  `"solidity.formatter": "prettier"` in settings.json but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

The issue was with the Solidity by Juan extension new version 0.0.169, I don't know why it was not working with Prettier. I reverted back to version 0.0.169 and it was working.